# Not sure what different about theoretical and practical method

Tags: calculus

Calculate the discounted value of $5000 for 17 months at compound
interest rate j2 = 6% using both the theoretical and practical method.
could anyone help

Comment: You need to add more context

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You are more likely to get useful help on this site if you explain what you've tried so far, where you are stuck. Otherwise you are likely to get downvoted or have your question closed.